# Utilitzar una lista generada en otro fichero Python

Tags: python

Tengo un fichero Python con una función donde genero una lista. Esta lista la voy a utilizar en otros fichero Python. Lo estoy haciendo importando la función del Python que genera la lista.

¿Cómo hago para cargar la lista en los otros ficheros?

Código del Python que genera la lista:

```
def elementID (my_list):

    input_file_path = "archivo.txt"
    my_list = []
    with open(input_file_path, "r") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            str = line.strip()
            my_list.append(str)
```

Comment: devuelve la lista: `return my_list`.

Comment: Hola @fedorqui entiendo que te refieres a que ponga {return my_list} como última linea a nivel del with ¿no?

Comment: no, me refiero a que la función devuelva la lista. Así, siempre que quieras la lista harás `lista_que_quiero = elementeID(bla)`.

Comment: Eso sí, sería bueno que explicaras qué quieres hacer exactamente para entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación @fedorqui. Ya funciona. Abajo me he respondido con tú ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Código donde se obtiene la lista:

```
#def elementID ():
#
#    input_file_path = "Elements_to_extract_forces.txt"
#    elements_list = []
#    with open(input_file_path, "r") as in_file:
#        for line in in_file:
#            str = line.strip()
#            elements_list.append(str)
#        #print elements_list
#    return elements_list

def elementID ():
    input_file_path = "Elements_to_extract_forces.txt"
    with open(input_file_path, "r") as in_file:
        return [line.strip() for line in in_file]
```

Código para otro fichero Python donde cargamos la lista generada antes:

```
from Read_element_IDs import elementID
element_list = elementID()
print element_list
```

Imprime por pantalla la lista. Funciona.

Comment: Unas observaciones Manuel: los imports  wildcards `from módulo import *` son considerados una mala práctica por varias razones (igual que el típico `using std;` en c++), puedes importar con `from generate_list import elementID`, o mejor mediante `import `generate_list` y luego llamar con `my_list = generate_list.elementID()`. No debes nunca usar `str` como identificador de una variable, en todo caso `str_`, con eso sobrescribes el built-in `str` de Python. Por último, aunque correcto es mucho más eficiente usar una lista por compresión `return [line.strip() for line in in_file]`. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla siempre se aprende de tus comentarios. ¿Por qué es mejor `import generate_list` y luego llamar con `generate_list.elementID()` que directamente hacer `from generate_list import elementID`?

Comment: Ok, gracias por la explicación. Cambio from módulo import * por import módulo. Cambio str por element_id y cambio a lista por compresión.

Comment: @fedorqui en este caso casi que da igual siempre y cuando tengas cuidado de no crear otro identificador llamado `elementID` en el script actual. Otro tema es que tengas que importar 100 funciones de esta forma... La razón por la que se prefiere `generate_list.elementID()` es porque de forma **explícita** estás indicando que usas `elementID` del espacio de nombres `generate_list`, esto facilita la lectura del código por otros ya que no hay que adivinar de donde viene la función, por otro lado podemos usar el identificador `elementID` en nuestro script o en otros importados sin riesgos.

Comment: El mantra de "explícito mejor que implícito" de Python va más lejos de la legibilidad en este caso, me he encontrado con errores nefastos que no provocaban excepciones, solo salidas no esperadas porque alguien sin querer sobrescribió una variable, constante, función, clase, de un módulo importado vía `*`. Esto en códigos pequeños es fácil de detectar, pero cuando tienes un paquete con 5000 líneas te aseguro que te acuerdas del que quiso ahorrase el namespace a la hora de hacer referencia a la función importada... XD

Comment: @FJSevilla caramba, cómo se nota cuando alguien ha estado metido en proyectos grandes :) Gracias por la explicación, la tendré en cuenta.